# How to get only number from text in MIT app Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

E.g. "Ganeshkhind, Pune, Maharashtra 411007" from this string I want extract only pincode i.e. 411007

Comment: You should try to learn how to make a Google search first, before taking on Android development....

Comment: http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/text.html#splitatspaces

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SplitAtSpaces block and the IsNumber boolean together to get the number.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqZLW.png)